# listing only questions correlates with user in rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
I have the following models:
```

- USER
- SURVEY
- DIMENSION
- QUESTION

  The following relationships:
- USER (has_many) -> SURVEYS
- SURVEY (has_many) -> DIMENSIONS
- DIMENSION (has_many) -> QUESTIONS

  ===============================

  I need to list the QUESTIONS only for one USER. For example: The USER with id = 1 was login. So will just list the QUESTIONS that USER.

  I tried with sql manually using INNER JOINS, but I could not. Can anyone give me a hint.
  I also tried with @question.dimension.survey.user_id = @current_user , but had not success

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

The below query will work for sure. Try this.

`@questions = current_user.surveys.map{|d| d.dimensions}.map{|q| q.questions}` 
If you give the current user manually, you can go like this 
`@questions = User.find(1).surveys.map{|d| d.dimensions}.map{|q| q.questions}` for user id=1

Comment: According to user id(ie '1') , you can write as `@questions = User.find(1).surveys.map{|d| d.dimensions}.map{|q| q.questions}`

Comment: did not work.did not work.
Look, I want to list QUESTIONS only the USER logged and all appear here.

Comment: I decided well, I do not know if it's the best way:

Answer (score 0):

I decided well, I do not know if it's the best way (in app/controllers/question_controller.rb):

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<% if (question.dimension.survey.user_id == @current_user.id) %>
<tr>
<td><%= question.dimension.survey.user.name %></td>
<td><%= question.dimension.survey.title %></td>
<td><%= question.dimension.name %></td>
<td><%= question.question %></td>
<td><%= question.order %></td>
<td><%= question.status %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show', question %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_question_path(question) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', question, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```